# Cannot format input parameters correctly for SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

So here's the deal, I have a stored procedure that accepts in three input parameters and has one output parameter.  Originally it looked like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestIDForAnalyte @ThisWOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60), @TestId int OUT
AS
   SELECT @TestID = t1.TestID
   FROM tblWOSampleTest t1 JOIN tblTest t2
   ON t1.TestID=t2.TestID 
   WHERE (t1.SampleID =  @SampleID) AND (t2.Analyte =  @Analyte)  AND (t1.WOID = @ThisWoid) 
   SELECT @TestID =ISNULL(@Testid,0) 
Go
```

It worked great when executed on MS-SQL Server Management Studio 2008, but when called in MS-Access 2010 (VBA) I would get the following error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1406-00591' to data type int. (My @ThisWoid input)

So basically I posted a question about this and I posted everything(The way I called the stored procedure/ the datatypes of the table columns..ect) and I was told everything looked fine and it probably had something to do with the values I was assigning to my input parameters, I'll post the link to the previous question at the bottom  of the page if anyone is curious.  I found kind of a loop hole to get rid of this error by using 'LIKE' instead of '=' because the data type constraint isn't as strict for 'LIKE' (I know not the best solution but I'm desperate to make progress).  Anyways so now my SQL code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestIDForAnalyte2 @ThisWOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60), @TestId int OUT
AS
   SELECT @TestID = t1.TestID
   FROM tblWOSampleTest t1 JOIN tblTest t2
   ON t1.TestID=t2.TestID 
   WHERE (t1.SampleID LIKE  @SampleID) AND (t2.Analyte Like  @Analyte)  AND (t1.WOID Like @ThisWoid) 
   SELECT @TestID =ISNULL(@Testid,0) 
go
```

Again it works great in SQL Management Studio but when I call it in MS-Access it always returns 0.  SO for a little test I changed the SQL code once more to see if it can return something other than zero by forcing values that I knew would definitely return a value, here is that code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestIDForAnalyte3 @ThisWOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60), @TestID int out
AS
   Select @TestID = t1.testid 
   From tblWOSampleTest t1 JOIN tbltest t2 
   On t1.testid = t2.testid
   Where  (t1.woid LIKE '1406-00591') AND (t2.Analyte LIKE 'lead') AND (t1.SampleID LIKE 1)
   SELECT @TestID =ISNULL(@Testid,0) 
Go
```

finally yes the correct output was saved to @TestID.  So Great I was making some progress. (Sort of).  So then I get curious and change the 'LIKE' back to '=' and it returns the correct value! At this point I don't really know whats going on but I just roll with it.  SO then I change my SQL code back to upGetTestIDForAnalyte2 (I labeled them all differently btw) and when I call my stored procedure I take those same values and assign them to the input parameters like such:

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "upGetTestIDForAnalyte2"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Analyte", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "lead")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ThisWOID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "1406-00591")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SampleID", adDouble, adParamInput, 60, 1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@testid", adDouble, adParamOutput, , adParamReturnValue)
    cmd.Execute
    Conn.Close

    ThisTestID = cmd.Parameters("@testid").Value
```

It returns always sets TestId to 0.  I also initialized my ThisTestID to 5 to make sure its changing, and it is changing to 0.  Just to make sure I ran upGetTestIDForAnalyte with the same input values and i got the same error as I got above.  So this is where I am right now.  Here is some inforamtion on the tables i am using I got from the SQL code:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC
where (TABLE_NAME = 'tblwosampletest' and COLUMN_NAME = 'woid')
  OR (TABLE_NAME = 'tblwosampletest' and COLUMN_NAME = 'sampleID')
  OR (TABLE_NAME = 'tbltest' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Analyte)'
```

Results: [image] 
Also I define my Variables to pass as:

```
Dim Analyte As String
Dim ThisWOID As String
Dim ThisSampleID As Long
Dim ThisTestID As Long
```

Link to previous question (not gonna lie it's kind of confusing) [Unknown invalid type converson in my SQL stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416178/unknown-invalid-type-converson-in-my-sql-stored-procedure)
Okay if Anyone needs more information or clarification just ask, Thanks for the help! Also if you don't know the answer could you suggest tests I could do.

Comment: I just happened to notice that the cases on your VBA code and stored procedure are different for TestId  - IN your VBA code it is "@testid" and in stored procedure it is  "@TestId". Not sure if it is case sensitive. Can you make it consistent and try again for your example with upGetTestIDForAnalyte2?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for tests I could do?

Comment: As a test of your input variables, create a table in SQL, and in your proc, insert your variables into the table and then see what's writing.  Confirm your variables are making into the proc... take baby steps until you find out where something cracks.

Comment: Also SampleID is an INT in SQL... but your proc variable is nvarchar.  Also your vb code parameter order doesn't match the SQL input parameter order... i believe unless you specify `cmd.NamedParameters = True` then the parameters are used in ordinal order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable order is out of order with the PROC.

Your VB order is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Analyte", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "lead")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ThisWOID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "1406-00591")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SampleID", adDouble, adParamInput, 60, 1)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@testid", adDouble, adParamOutput, , adParamReturnValue)
```

And your proc order is:

```
@ThisWOID nvarchar(60), 
@SampleID nvarchar(60),
@Analyte nvarchar(60), 
@TestID int out
```

Unless you specifiy in vb that `cmd.NamedParameters=True` then the ordinal order is used, and thus your vb `@Analyte` is put into the SQL `@ThisWOID`, and the vb `@ThisWOID` is put into the SQL `@SampleID` -- which is likely your `NVARCHAR-INT` conversion issue.

Get your names in order, or set the named params attribute to true, and fix your SQL proc so that `@SampleID` is an `INT` to match your table.

You should be golden after that.